# How to execute stored procedure from java?

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from java, but it's not executing. Instead, I get this error:

> ERROR 651 - ORA-06550: line 15, column 1:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.
>
> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 15, column 1: PLS-00103:
> Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)

Please find the stored procedure and java code here:

Stored procedure:

```
        DECLARE BEGIN EMPLOYEE ($id$); END; /
```

Java code:

```
Statement st = connection.prepareCall(sp); 
int r = st.executeBatch();
```

Please need input.

Comment: i am passing 'id' from cmd and replacing 'id'.

Comment: Is this Stored Procedure compiled in your DB? Which DB are you using? Or are you passing this as an anonymous PLSQL block of code in Java directly?

Comment: I have more then one Stored Procedure in my oracle DB, Stored Procedure is calling by java DECLARE BEGIN EMPLOYEE ($id$); END; / by passing and replacing 'id' from cmd. If i am keeping / then getting error above and it i not keeping so its executing but db update is not happening